# How to set PATH from python code?

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried setting ORACLE_HOME path from python script as below but it didn't work, any idea how can I set it?

```
>>> subprocess.call(["export", "ORACLE_HOME="+ORACLE_HOME], env= os.environ)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 419, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> subprocess.call(["export", "ORACLE_HOME="+ORACLE_HOME])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 419, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.environ`:

```
os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = 'whatever'
```

Comment: great.. thanks a lot. Any idea how to append to an existing PATH ?

Comment: @Shashi: `os.environ['PATH'] += ':whatever'`